# Android Studio - Device File Explorer: Permission denied

Tags: android-studio, mobile

I am trying to access the Device File Explorer but I keep getting Permission denied. Have not been able to find a solution online anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

[Android Studio photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kB962.png)

Comment: Have you add the permission in manifest?

Comment: Did you find solution?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem: I could not access storage\emulated because it kept telling me that I had no permissions.
I found no answers on internet, but I created a new emulator (Nexus_One) with android's version lollipop (5.1), and at first I did not find any directory inside storage. I right clicked, selected upload and uploaded a file. Then I could see all the directories inside storage. I right clicked on emulated, uploaded a file, and finally got the directory 0 where I needed to upload the real file.
However, this trick did not work on the emulators I already had (Nexux 5).
It is not a solution, but I hope it helps!

Answer (score -1):

'/storage/emulated/0/' like a abstract path, you can upload file on sdcard/,and visit it use '/storage/emulated/0/' in android code.For example,if you want to visit a test.txt in '/storage/emulated/0/myFiles/test/test.txt'(code path), you should upload the test.txt in 'sdcard/test/test.txt'(in Device File Explorer,AS).

Comment: Instead of /storage/emulated/0/ which gives me "Permission denied" error， I found the file I created using java code with the path "/storage/emulated/0/Android/data..." is actually under /sdcard/Android/data/... So this answer gave me the tips to find the real place.